# Performing DNAT for AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-networking

Is there any way to perform DNAT for AWS EC2 instances?  I am trying to allocate one public ip and then associate this ip with any instance under my public subnet.  We can perform similar action in VMware's NSX using DNAT rules but don't find it's equivalent in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [AWS Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) is a static public IP address that can be moved between any of your EC2 instances. AWS is using NAT behind the scenes to make that work.

If you want an AWS Elastic IP to point to more than one of your EC2 instances at the same time, you can assign it to an [AWS Network Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html).

Comment: Mark, I had one more question - can we add multiple public ips to the same instance? The way I am trying to do this attaching multiple network instances to the same ec2 and then assigning them an elastic ip

Comment: Yes, but I think you will have to assign multiple [Elastic Network Interfaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html) to the instance.